# Code only work when using Irrefutable patterns

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have 2 files [a.hs](https://gist.github.com/wizzup/5af26430046d7b71ed2b93ff5cec2add#file-a-hs) and [b.hs](https://gist.github.com/wizzup/5af26430046d7b71ed2b93ff5cec2add#file-b-hs) that have different only one is use `~` but another one is use explicit match

```
$ diff a.hs b.hs
20,21c20
<       (True,  js) -> (True,  a:js)
<       (False, js) -> (False, b:js)
---
>       ~(i, js) -> (i, (if i then a else b):js)
```

This is portion of code that use the pattern that run fine.

```
shortest :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
shortest xs ys = snd $ shortest' xs ys where
  shortest' :: [a] -> [a] -> (Bool, [a])
  shortest' []     _      = (True,  [])
  shortest'  _     []     = (False, [])
  shortest' (a:as) (b:bs) = case shortest' as bs of
      ~(i, js) -> (i, (if i then a else b):js)
```

but when I use

```
(True,  js) -> (True,  a:js)
(False, js) -> (False, b:js)
```

my computer is not responding (memory almost full).

**Am I missing any patterns?**

The whole files can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/wizzup/5af26430046d7b71ed2b93ff5cec2add)
. (wonder if SO support embedded gist)

I didn't wrote the code originally, it is a modified version of flickyfrans's [gist](https://gist.github.com/flickyfrans/b843b20bb512be443b4b)

---

**Edit:** I think I should post `b.hs` here to prevent link rotted problem in the future.

```
import Data.Maybe

data Rose  a = Rose a [Rose a] deriving Show
newtype Graph a = Graph [(a, Rose a)]

lookupRose :: Eq a => a -> Graph a -> Rose a
lookupRose i (Graph rs) = fromJust $ lookup i rs

fromList :: Eq a => [(a, [a])] -> Graph a
fromList xs = graph where
  graph         = Graph $ map irose xs
  irose (i, is) = (i, Rose i $ map (`lookupRose` graph) is)

shortest :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
shortest xs ys = snd $ shortest' xs ys where
  shortest' :: [a] -> [a] -> (Bool, [a])
  shortest' []     _      = (True,  [])
  shortest'  _     []     = (False, [])
  shortest' (a:as) (b:bs) = case shortest' as bs of
      ~(i, js) -> (i, (if i then a else b):js)

path :: Eq a => a -> a -> Graph a -> [a]
path orig dest gr = path' (lookupRose orig gr) where
  path' (Rose p ps)
      | p == dest = [p]
      | otherwise = p : foldr1 shortest (map path' ps)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Pos = (Int,Int)

posGraph :: [(Pos,[Pos])]
posGraph = [ (a, [b, c, d])
          , (b, [a, b, d])
          , (c, [a, d, e])
          , (d, [a, b, c, g])
          , (e, [c, e, f, h])
          , (f, [e, g, h])
          , (g, [d, f, g])
          , (h, [e, f])
          ]
  where [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h] =
          [ (1,1)
          , (2,2)
          , (3,3)
          , (4,4)
          , (5,5)
          , (6,6)
          , (7,7)
          , (8,8)
          ]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ path (1,1) (8,8) $ fromList posGraph
  print $ path (2,2) (8,8) $ fromList posGraph
```

Comment: Can you give an example? Because with `True`/`False`, the program works for me, and Haskell does not show any errors.

Comment: I think the issue is that, with a regular pattern matching, your function is stricter, and later on in your program you use `foldr1 shortest ...`. Using a `foldr` with a strict function is not a good idea, since it will immediately perform all the recursive calls before it can return anything, using a lot of memory.

Comment: No, SO does not support embedded gist, and it probably will never support them. Gists can get deleted any time, which would devalue the question.

Comment: ***Warning:*** If you run wizzup's code, make sure to compile with `-rtsopts` and use `+RTS -M2G` or similar, unless you really like swapping memory.

Comment: The issue is not with matching on `Bool`. The issue is that the pattern `(x, True)` or `(x, False)` or even `(x, y)` are strict on the *tuple*. By writing `~(x,y)` you not only have a lazy match on the `Bool`, but on the tuple as well. Try as well a lazy match on just the `Bool`, i.e. `(x, ~y)` (hint: you'll get a warning because the `~` is redundant there - and it will blow up the stack, being exactly the same as just `(x,y)`) and also `let (x,y) = shortest' .. in ..` (it will work, because pattern matches in `let` bindings are by default lazy, whereas in `case` it is by default strict).

Comment: Aside: I'm not sure what the question here is (what does "Am I missing any patterns?" mean?). If it is about why this works the way it does, please read the Haskell report - that goes into the semantics of pattern matching in some detail.